# Custom RES SCREENS and RES ICONS get replaced with default Cordova screen and icon

Tags: android, cordova, icons, splash-screen, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio tools for Apache Cordova.

I've tested the CLI 6.4.0 and unfortunately there is a bug with the RES SCREENS and RES ICONS. If I use CLI 6.3.1 this issue disappears. To demonstrate it I've created a new project from scratch, added only the cordova-plugin-splashscreen (ver 4.0.0) and replaced the original screen images with custom ones.

The issue happens when I try to debug with a physical android device connected via USB.

On build the system automatically creates some extra folders/files (one new folder/file for each splash configuration I have in my config.xml), so in my case I get these new folders/files:

- res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png
- res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png
- res/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png
- res/drawable-land-xdpi/screen.png
- res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png
- res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png
- res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png
- res/drawable-port-xdpi/screen.png

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

### [image]

The PNG files reflects what I have in my RES/SCREENS/ANDROID folders.

At the same time the build copies these new folders (described above) to the PLATFORMS/ANDROID/RES folder. The issue is the images inside those folders are not the original ones I have chosen in my project, but they are the Cordova Logo (the one that is added by default when a new project is created).

---

[image]

Comment: I made a demo and reproduced your problem. I've reported it on official website [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12092). Let's wait for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Elvis for pointing it out! Your bug report has been closed because it's a duplicate issue.

Here is the link to the official bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12077

And here is the GitHub Pull Request:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/343

Comment: I see this issue got introduced in 6.3.1.  It works for me if I use 6.3.0.  Otherwise anything above that its broken.

Comment: @SpoiledTechie.com It is not necessary to downgrade Cordova. Problem will be solved by (forced) upgrading the Android platform to version 6.1.0: `cordova platform update android@6.1.0`