# Taco does not build android icons

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I am currently building my first mobile application with Microsoft Visual Studio ( Community 2015 ).

The build is successful for Android, but the icon images are not being created properly for the platform. The reason I say this is because the images that are created under platforms/android/res/mipmap-* are the default Cordova icons rather than my icons.

I am using Cordova CLI 6.4.0.

The relevant lines in my config.xml file:

```
<platform name="android">
  <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
  <icon src="res/icons/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Could you try defining it from the root www folder? Something like - <icon src="www/ts/images/icon.png" />

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315481/custom-res-screens-and-res-icons-get-replaced-with-default-cordova-screen-and-ic

Comment: @gandhi There is bug in cordova-android version of 6.4.0, so I don't think that your suggestion will help.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Its fixed now i guess

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem of icons not being copied is to add the following line in the config.xml file:

You can edit the config.xml file in Microsoft Visual Studio by right clicking on the config.xml file and select "view code".